# Custom Syntax Highlighter in Visual Studio for Shopify .liquid Files

Tags: visual-studio, shopify, intellisense, liquid, syntaxhighlighter

I'm currently working in a Shopify project which I have integrated to work locally. I'm using Visual Studio as my IDE which is super awesome. When working with .liquid files, I treat the extension to be opened with HTML editor with encoding. This is pretty sweet, but then I think it will be even better if I can have a syntax highlighting done for all the 'liquid' specific syntax, especially **{%** and **%}** since **{{** and **}}** have been highlighted thanks to AngularJS syntax I reckon.

I found out that there are libraries to provide better intellisense, but not for .liquid files. What's the best way to get started with configuring a custom syntax highlighter? Will this be a quick process to do?

**Screenshot**:
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Seeing this question just received an upvote, let me post my solution here.

### (Especially) For Windows Developers

Your best choice is to use [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), which is a lightweight, cross-platform source code editor by Microsoft. There's an extension called [Liquid Languages Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=neilding.language-liquid) by Neil Ding which I used

[image: liquid-languages-support-syntax-highlight-SO-kent]

**Alternative**: There seems to be a better extension called [Shopify Liquid Template Snippets](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=killalau.vscode-liquid-snippets) by Franky Lau, which I haven't tested. Can anyone who has used this share their insights?

### Theme Kit

If you are looking on how to upload your local changes directly to your development theme, or an alternative workflow for Mac/Linux users, check out [Shopify Theme Kit](http://shopify.github.io/themekit/).

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tried it but there is a [liquid highlighting extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=igorfle.VSLiquidSyntax&ssr=false#overview) for VS 2017 / 2019

Comment: @Marek a +1 then ?

Comment: It can't do liquid/html formatting which makes it hard to use.

Answer (score -1):

Best extension I have found to date is [VS Code Liquid](https://github.com/panoply/vscode-liquid) by Nikolas Savvidis. I'm pretty confident it will handle the sorts of situations you've described.

I use Locomotive CMS which also requires mixed code types within files and Liquid Language Support can't handle it.